# defining the negative start parameter in substr as a variable

Tags: php, parameters, substr

Is using the following correct for defining the negative start parameter for a substr, 
 because  its the only way i know how to get it to retur the correct result.

```
$start == (-44); 
or
$start == (int) -44;

$pair = substr($str, $start, 4);
```

Comment: You can't use `substr($str, -44, 4);`? What error does show up if you try this?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Maybe we can suggest a different way to approach it. Also, as long as you aren't actually using `==` in your code rather than `$start = something`, either way is syntactically correct.

Comment: Also: is using the comparison operator a typo in your question or in your actual code? If you don't actually assign -44 to $start, I guess getting the result you expected must just be a coincident.

Comment: Maybe you can post an example string, so it will be easier for us to help.

Comment: @SvenS i could just set it substr($str, -44, 4); manually

Comment: @jprofitt im using quite a few conditions cases to store $start positions, and passing them out the the rest or the code out side of the case (i was using == in my code) only to because it was returing the correct result,

Comment: Since you were using `$start == ...` rather than actually assigning `$start`, your `substr()` call was most likely the equivalent of `substr($str, 0, 4);`. What are you trying to get out of the string? There's probably a regex that can take care of it. Can you provide some sample strings with the relevant `$start`?

Comment: follow up why i was getting the correct result with the ingorrect syntax because it was failing and returning 
wrong setting size to begin with :S, thanks to every one

Comment: @jprofitt ok here is a example, but i thought its better just to use substr for these operations rather than calling up the regexp engine

`string $star_tmp = -48;
$lenght_tmp = -44;


$str_tmp = "CgV1GyxCSRHMbzqH3yfVZWcJ0g4jIWeQw6KMzJeKLhElKLHK";

$first_4 = substr($str_tmp, $star_tmp, 4); // as ref;

$all_but_first_4 = substr($str_tmp, $lenght_tmp); // as ref;`

Comment: If you're just wanting everything past the first 4 characters, you can use `$all_but_first_4 = substr($str_tmp, 4);` and to get the first four `$first_4 = substr($str_temp, 0, 4);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `substr` call is valid, the only error in your code (posted here) is the `==` operator.

It should be:

```
$start = -44;
$pair = substr($str, $start, 4)
```

Also is the start value `-44` the 44th character from start or the end. The above code considers `-44` to mean *44th character from end of string*.

One more error you could run into is if the length of `$str` is less than 44.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add a `-` before an expression (including a variable) to invert its sign:

```
$pair = substr($str, -$start, 4);
```

Or

```
$pair = substr($str, -44, 4);
```